# I am getting this "The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown;" error while using xsl:result-document

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I am trying to write some content in a file using `xsl:result-document`. While compiling the code, I am getting this error

> The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown;".

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <title>This is an example document</title>
    <section>
        <title>This is section one</title>
        <p>This is the content of section one.</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <title>This is section two</title>
        <p>This is the content of section two.</p>
    </section>
</document>
```

XSLT processing:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/document">      
        <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <xsl:result-document href="section{position()}.html">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Result:

- `section1.html`:

  ```
  <title>This is section one</title>
  <p>This is the content of section one.</p>
  ```
- `section2.html`:

  ```
  <title>This is section two</title>
  <p>This is the content of section two.</p>
  ```

But I get the error Message:

> The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown;

Please guide me where I need to change.
This is the logic, I have tried

```
<xsl:for-each select="section">
  <xsl:result-document href="section{position()}.html">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: If you're using Saxon, to quote Michael Kay from a post on Saxon's forums: "If you're invoking this from the command line, you need to specify the -o option to give the principal output destination."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code was tested with `Saxon-HE 9.9.1.4J from Saxonica`. To get exactly the output you specified in your question, change your XSLT-2.0 stylesheet to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/document">      
        <xsl:for-each select="section">
            <xsl:result-document href="section{position()}.html" omit-xml-declaration="yes">
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Two things were changed:

- `xsl:copy-of` was changed from `.` to `*` to select only all child elements
- A new attribute was added to `xsl:result-document` to omit the XML declaration.

**The outputted files are:**

- `section1.html`:

  ```
  <title>This is section one</title>
  <p>This is the content of section one.</p>
  ```
- `section2.html`:

  ```
  <title>This is section two</title>
  <p>This is the content of section two.</p>
  ```

This seems to be as desired.

Relating to your error message [a quote from a 2005 response of Michael Kay](https://www.oxygenxml.com/archives/xsl-list/200505/msg01126.html):

> If you invoke Saxon from the command line without specifying the -o option, the principal output goes to standard out, which has no known URI, so you get this failure. The answer is to specify the -o option. (I've fixed this recently so that if -o is not specified,
>   parents.xml will go in the current directory, if you're executng from the command line - but not if Saxon is called using the Java API).

My test has been done with the current Java version of Saxon, so it should work now.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I too used SaxonHE9-9-1-4J in Spring Tool Suite. It has these jar files- saxon9he.jar
saxon9-test.jar
saxon9-xqj.jar. Still, I am getting the same error. Can you show me how you executed?

Comment: I just used `java -jar saxon9he.jar -xsl:transform.xslt input.xml` and the output is directed to the two files `section1.html` and `section2.html`.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see how you are invoking the transformation. Basically, you need to specify a principal output destination (even if you never write to it), and this needs to have a known URI (so secondary result destinations in xsl:result-document can be resolved. The means, for example, that if it is a StreamResult it must have a known systemId.