# xsl:result-document throws "The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown" error

Tags: split, xslt-2.0, saxon

I am trying to split output into multiple file by using xsl:result-document. But I am getting error as "The system identifier of the principal output file is unknown".

Input XML:

```
<ArrayOfBatch>
 <Batch>
  <BatchName>BatchName-1</BatchName>
 </Batch>
 <Batch>
  <BatchName>BatchName-2</BatchName>
 </Batch>
 <Batch>
  <BatchName>BatchName-3</BatchName>
 </Batch>
</ArrayOfBatch>
```

XSLT Format:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="3.0" exclude-result-prefixes="fn xs">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/ArrayOfBatch/Batch">
   <xsl:result-document href="Batch-{position()}.xml" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes">
    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
   </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We are using .Net to run xslt with below transformation

```
public static string SaxonProcessorXSLT(string xmlToExport, string xslStylesheet)
{
  using (StringReader xmlStream = new StringReader(xmlToExport))
  {
    using (StringReader xslStream = new StringReader(xslStylesheet))
    {
      Processor xsltProcessor = new Processor();
      DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = xsltProcessor.NewDocumentBuilder();
      documentBuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("file://");
      XdmNode xdmNode = documentBuilder.Build(xmlStream);

      XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = xsltProcessor.NewXsltCompiler();
      XsltExecutable xsltExecutable = xsltCompiler.Compile(xslStream);
      XsltTransformer xsltTransformer = xsltExecutable.Load();
      xsltTransformer.InitialContextNode = xdmNode;

      using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
      {
        Serializer serializer = xsltProcessor.NewSerializer();
        serializer.SetOutputWriter(stringWriter);
        xsltTransformer.Run(serializer);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have done some R&D on this and found the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57638329/i-am-getting-this-the-system-identifier-of-the-principal-output-file-is-unknown) but its not solving my problem. I have tried by using SAXON-HE and SAXON-EE (dll) on version 2.0 and 3.0. Looking for quick response. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So which version of Saxon exactly do you use? Do you run it from the command line or with Java or .Net code? Show us all details to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen We are using .Net and Saxon-EE dll.

Comment: How do you use it, show us the exact code (C# or VB.NET) to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you want all results in memory, as strings, or do you want to write the splitted batches to files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given a relative URI in the `@href` attribute of `xsl:result-document`. This is treated as being relative to the "principal output URI" of the transformation. The error message is telling you that the principal output URI has not been supplied. This is because you invoked the transformation without supplying it.

You haven't told us how you invoked the transformation. The details will depend on whether you used the command line, the JAXP transformation API, the s9api transformation API, or perhaps the fn:transform() function. Each of these APIs gives you an opportunity to supply the required URI.

Perhaps the most common reason for the problem (but now I'm guessing) is that you used the JAXP transformation API, and specified as the destination for the transformation a `StreamResult` containing a `Stream` or `Writer` but no `systemId`.

(I'm a little surprised that you should link to another question in which I gave exactly the same information, and stressed that to answer it in detail, we need to see how you invoked the transformation. Many people would close this as a duplicate...)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response @michaelkey, I have update the question above with transformation logic. Please review and let me know what am I missing there.

Comment: As suspected. You're using the Saxon.Api interface on .NET, sending the output to a `Serializer` that wraps a `StringWriter`, which is a destination with no known base URI. You need to set the `BaseOutputUri` property on the `XsltTransformer` before calling `Run()`. Set it to the directory into which you want the output files written (as a URI, not a filename).

Comment: Thank you so @michaelKay, it works :) But how to set Azure and TFS path there with credential ?

Comment: Azure is just a name to me, and TFS isn't even that, so I'm afraid you'll need to put that part to someone who knows those technologies.